# Proving alternating sum of dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

After researching this result, I believe it is called the "Euler characteristic," but I don't know exactly how to describe it.

The set-up is: I have an infinite sequence of finite-dimensional vector spaces $\ldots, W_{m-1}, W_m, W_{m+1}, \ldots$, only finitely many of which have dimension greater than zero, and maps $f_m: W_m \to W_{m+1}$ and they form a complex, so that the image of $f_m$ is contained in the kernel of $f_{m+1}$. The $m$th comohomology group is then defined to be the quotient $H_m = \frac{\text{ker}(f_m)}{\text{Im}(f_{m-1})}$. My goal is to prove the alternating sum
$$
\sum\limits (-1)^m \dim W_m = \sum (-1)^m \dim H_m.  
$$
I'm a bit mystified with how to get started, and whether it makes sense to work from the left-hand side or right-hand side. The assumption that only finitely many of the vector spaces are non-zero should guarantee that the sums converge, but I think is otherwise un-used. I can say that
$$
\dim H_m = \dim \text{ker}(f_m) - \text{Im}(f_{m-1}). 
$$
As $\text{Im}(f_m) \subset \text{ker}(f_{m+1})$, I know that I can say $\dim \text{Im}(f_m) \leq \dim \text{ker}(f_{m+1})$, but I don't think this will help me, as I'm looking to prove an equality. The rank nullity theorem lets me say
$$
\dim W_m = \dim \text{Im}(f_m) + \dim \text{ker}(f_m). 
$$
I see a common term in $\dim \text{ker}(f_m)$ so I could try to subtract these equations, but I don't think that will help unless I want to work from the middle out.

I'd greatly appreciate any help on parsing this problem.

Comment: There's something screwy going on with your indexing where $m$ is sometimes replaced by $i$ but in a way that doesn't make sense to me, e.g. where you define the map $f_m: W_i \to W_{i+1}$. Do you intend the usual notation for a chain map $f_m: W_m \to W_{m+1}$ for each $m$?

Comment: @SammyBlack Sorry about that. I will edit to use $m$ consistently.

Comment: this is shown in Hatcher, I think

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem is exactly the right thing to use.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Which map should I apply it to, though? Applied to the $f_m$, it doesn't seem to help. I can consider the quotient map from $\text{Im}(f_{m-1})$ to $\text{(Ker)}(\phi_m)/\text{Im}(\phi_{m-1})$. This map is definitely surjective and its kernel is $\text{Im}(\phi_{m-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$It is fair to consider this finite complex as indexed over all of $\Bbb Z$, taking other maps as $0\to0$ and thus other kernels and images as zero too.

Then: $$\begin{align}\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m\dim W_m&=\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m(\dim\im f_m+\dim\ker f_m)\\&=\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m\dim\im f_m+\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m\dim\ker f_m\\&=\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^{m-1}\dim\im f_{m-1}+\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m\dim\ker f_m\\&=-\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m\dim\im f_{m-1}+\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m\dim\ker f_m\\&=\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^m\dim H_m\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track! Those two displayed equations for $\dim H_m$ and $\dim W_m$ are exactly what you need. Notice how the only minus sign occurs in a term involving the dimension of a space whose index is shifted by $1$, which plays nicely with the alternating sign in our sums.

Try this again before revealing the spoiler.

> \begin{align} \sum_m (-1)^m \dim W_m &= \sum_m (-1)^m (\dim \ker f_m + \dim \operatorname{im} f_m) \\ &= \sum_m (-1)^m \dim \ker f_m + \sum_m (-1)^m \dim \operatorname{im} f_m \\ &= \sum_m (-1)^m \dim \ker f_m + \sum_m (-1)^{m-1} \dim \operatorname{im} f_{m-1} \\ &= \sum_m (-1)^m \dim \ker f_m - \sum_m (-1)^m \dim \operatorname{im} f_{m-1} \\ &= \sum_m (-1)^m (\dim \ker f_m - \dim \operatorname{im} f_{m-1}) \\ &= \sum_m (-1)^m \dim H_m \end{align}